# reading cell array using jmatio

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to read from a matlab cell array of strings using the java library jmatio
This is my code

```
 MatFileReader matreader=new MatFileReader ("filepath");
 MLarray array= matreader.getMLArray ("cellData").contentToString ());
```

If I print out  array I get an out put that shows me an array with the correct dimensions but in place of the cell elements it tells me the size of the character array in the cell. For example if the first cell contained a string of 5 characters it would show the following
     [1×5 char array]
The information is correct but I would like to access the actual information of the cell.
When I used MLCell as in the following I only get the  dimensions of the array itself .

```
 Int [] dims = matreader.getMLArray.getDimensions ();
 MLCell cellarr=new MLCell("celldata", dims);
```

Does anyone know the correct usage.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `get`-Function to get an element from the MLCell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used cellarr.get (index)  but the reply I got was [0×0 double array ]  when I printed out . Could you please tell me a little more specifically how to use the function.